# How to find an error in a pom.xml file?

Tags: pom.xml

Can anyone please help me to find out the error the below pom.xml file
=============================================        =

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>Test_grp_allure_report</groupId>
      <artifactId>Test_allure_report</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>Test_allure_report_graph</name>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker-gae</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>.com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId> extentreports </artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </project>





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7L7A.png
```

Comment: `project>` should be `<project>`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No problems here. When I copy your code and format it Maven has no problems with it :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test_grp_allure_report</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test_allure_report</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test_allure_report_graph</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker-gae</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>.com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId> extentreports </artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```